# jqgrid: issue with scrolling subgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm currently using jqgrid 4.8.2  I have a parent grid with a fixed width of 800 px, and a sub grid that is larger.  I've set both the parent grid and the child grid so that shrinkToFit is false.  A scroll bar for the sub grid appears and works properly.  Unfortunately, when I scroll the sub grid, the data row from the parent grid scrolls as well, but not the parent grid header.

I tried to replicate this experience using jsFiddle, but for some reason the jqgrid works differently there.  I don't get the scroll bar for the sub grid, even though the code I'm running on my server is exactly the same.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var mainGrid = {
  "total": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "pageSize": 20,
  "records": 1,
  "rows": [{
    "siteId": 12516086,
    "siteName": "Detroit",
    "siteAddress": "1 Woodward",
    "siteCitySt": "Detroit, MI",
    "siteZip": "48205",
    "productCd": "ProductX",
    "productName": "Product X",
    "finishedSize": null,
    "estimatedPieceWeight": 0.125,
    "vdpTypeCode": null,
    "taHouseholds": 1071689,
    "taDistribution": 445139,
    "distribution": 445139,
    "avgCpm": 32.32084084084084084084084084084084084084,
    "investment": 19542.8,
    "coverage": 41.54
  }]
};

var subGrid = {
  "total": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "pageSize": 20,
  "records": 2,
  "rows": [{
    "mediaPlanId": 3003,
    "mbuHdrId": 4035986,
    "mbuDtlId": 10442611,
    "commonMbuId": 99731,
    "ggId": 1244425,
    "fkGeoProfileId": 15032061,
    "fkSite": 12516086,
    "wrapZoneId": 15049936,
    "wrapZone": "MI Detroit/ Highland Park/ Hamtramck",
    "productCd": "INS_SHARED",
    "productName": "Insert - Shared Mail",
    "wrapPagePosition": null,
    "finishedSize": null,
    "estimatedPieceWeight": 0.125,
    "vdpTypeCode": null,
    "geocode": "48205D1",
    "zip": "48205",
    "atz": "D1",
    "cityName": "DETROIT, MI",
    "households": 2088,
    "taHouseholds": 2088,
    "distribution": 2092,
    "cpm": 0,
    "investment": 0.0,
    "overallCoverage": 100.191570881226053639846743295019157088,
    "taCoverage": 100.191570881226053639846743295019157088,
    "distance": 0.62,
    "coverageDescDisplay": "Pcd",
    "coverageDesc": "Private Carrier Delivery",
    "ihDate": 1463371200000,
    "ihDay": "M/T",
    "pricingMarket": "MI DETROIT",
    "fkSdmId": 15075973,
    "sdmName": "MI Detroit",
    "fkVariableId": 7039,
    "primaryVariableName": "Candy & Chewing Gum",
    "variableContents": "INDEX",
    "variableValue": 63.52,
    "isSelected": true,
    "isActiveMbuCmn": true,
    "isActiveMbuHdr": true,
    "isActiveMbuDtl": true,
    "isUsedInCbx": true,
    "isBought": true,
    "var1Name": "Candy & Chewing Gum",
    "var1Contents": "INDEX",
    "var1Value": "64",
    "var2Name": "Toys, Games, and Hobbies",
    "var2Contents": "INDEX",
    "var2Value": "74",
    "var3Name": "Casual Dining: Olive Garden",
    "var3Contents": "INDEX",
    "var3Value": "83"
  }, {
    "mediaPlanId": 3003,
    "mbuHdrId": 4035988,
    "mbuDtlId": 10442613,
    "commonMbuId": 99732,
    "ggId": 1244426,
    "fkGeoProfileId": 22973059,
    "fkSite": 12516086,
    "wrapZoneId": 15049936,
    "wrapZone": "MI Detroit/ Highland Park/ Hamtramck",
    "productCd": "INS_SHARED",
    "productName": "Insert - Shared Mail",
    "wrapPagePosition": null,
    "finishedSize": null,
    "estimatedPieceWeight": 0.125,
    "vdpTypeCode": null,
    "geocode": "48205G1",
    "zip": "48205",
    "atz": "G1",
    "cityName": "DETROIT, MI",
    "households": 1156,
    "taHouseholds": 1156,
    "distribution": 1157,
    "cpm": 0,
    "investment": 0.0,
    "overallCoverage": 100.086505190311418685121107266435986159,
    "taCoverage": 100.086505190311418685121107266435986159,
    "distance": 0.74,
    "coverageDescDisplay": "Pcd",
    "coverageDesc": "Private Carrier Delivery",
    "ihDate": 1463371200000,
    "ihDay": "M/T",
    "pricingMarket": "MI DETROIT",
    "fkSdmId": 15075973,
    "sdmName": "MI Detroit",
    "fkVariableId": 7039,
    "primaryVariableName": "Candy & Chewing Gum",
    "variableContents": "INDEX",
    "variableValue": 68.06,
    "isSelected": false,
    "isActiveMbuCmn": true,
    "isActiveMbuHdr": true,
    "isActiveMbuDtl": true,
    "isUsedInCbx": true,
    "isBought": false,
    "var1Name": "Candy & Chewing Gum",
    "var1Contents": "INDEX",
    "var1Value": "68",
    "var2Name": "Toys, Games, and Hobbies",
    "var2Contents": "INDEX",
    "var2Value": "78",
    "var3Name": "Casual Dining: Olive Garden",
    "var3Contents": "INDEX",
    "var3Value": "91"
  }]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    datatype: function(postdata) {

      $('#' + 'load_' + 'jqGrid').show();

      var json = mainGrid;

      for (var i = 0; i < json.rows.length; i++) {
        json.rows[i].id = $.jgrid.randId();
        json.rows[i].siteNameDisp = json.rows[i].siteName + ' - ' +
          json.rows[i].siteAddress + ', ' +
          json.rows[i].siteCitySt + ', ' +
          json.rows[i].siteZip;
      }

      var thegrid = $('#jqGrid')[0];
      thegrid.addJSONData(json);

      $('#' + 'load_' + 'jqGrid').hide();
    },
    page: 1,
    colModel: [{
      label: 'ID',
      name: 'id',
      width: 50,
      hidden: true,
      key: true,
      editable: true,
      sortable: false,
      editrules: {
        edithidden: true
      }
    }, {
      label: 'Site Id',
      name: 'siteId',
      width: 100,
      sortable: false,
      editable: true,
      hidden: true,
      editrules: {
        edithidden: true
      }
    }, {
      label: 'Site',
      name: 'siteNameDisp',
      width: 250,
      sortable: false
    }, {
      label: 'Trade Area Households',
      name: 'taHouseholds',
      width: 100,
      sortable: false,
      formatter: 'number',
      formatoptions: {
        thousandsSeparator: ",",
        decimalPlaces: 0
      },
      align: 'right'
    }, {
      label: 'Trade Area Distribution',
      name: 'taDistribution',
      width: 85,
      sortable: false,
      formatter: 'number',
      formatoptions: {
        thousandsSeparator: ",",
        decimalPlaces: 0
      },
      align: 'right'
    }, {
      label: 'Total Distribution',
      name: 'distribution',
      width: 85,
      sortable: false,
      formatter: 'number',
      formatoptions: {
        thousandsSeparator: ",",
        decimalPlaces: 0
      },
      align: 'right'
    }, {
      label: 'CPM',
      name: 'avgCpm',
      width: 50,
      sortable: false,
      formatter: 'currency',
      formatoptions: {
        decimalSeparator: ".",
        thousandsSeparator: ",",
        decimalPlaces: 2,
        prefix: "$ "
      },
      align: 'right'
    }, {
      label: 'Investment',
      name: 'investment',
      width: 75,
      sortable: false,
      formatter: 'currency',
      formatoptions: {
        decimalSeparator: ".",
        thousandsSeparator: ",",
        decimalPlaces: 2,
        prefix: "$ "
      },
      align: 'right'
    }, {
      label: 'Coverage %',
      name: 'coverage',
      width: 70,
      sortable: false,
      formatter: 'currency',
      formatoptions: {
        decimalSeparator: ".",
        thousandsSeparator: ",",
        decimalPlaces: 2,
        suffix: " %"
      },
      align: 'right'
    }, {
      label: 'Product',
      name: 'productCd',
      width: 150,
      sortable: false,
      editable: true,
      hidden: true,
      editrules: {
        edithidden: true
      }
    }],
    viewrecords: true,
    width: 800,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    //height: '100%',
    rowNum: 20,
    pager: "#jqGridPager",
    subGrid: true,
    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, parentRowId) {
      var grid = $("#jqGrid");
      var row = grid.getRowData(parentRowId);
      showDetail(subgrid_id, parentRowId);
    }
  });
});

function showDetail(subgrid_id, parentRowId) {
  var lastSelection;

  var parentGridId = 'jqGrid';

  var grid = $('#' + parentGridId);
  var row = grid.getRowData(parentRowId);
  var siteId = row.siteId;
  var productCode = row.productCd;

  var subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_table";
  var subgrid_pager_id = subgrid_id + "_pager";

  $("#" + subgrid_id).html("<table id=\'" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'></table>" +
    "<div id=\'" + subgrid_pager_id + "\'></div>");

  $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({

    datatype: function(postdata) {
      $('#' + 'load_' + subgrid_table_id).show();

      var json = subGrid;

      for (var i = 0; i < json.rows.length; i++) {
        json.rows[i].taDistribution = json.rows[i].distribution;
        json.rows[i].parentGridId = parentGridId;
        json.rows[i].parentRowId = parentRowId;
      }

      var thegrid = $("#" + subgrid_table_id)[0];
      thegrid.addJSONData(json);
      $('#' + 'load_' + subgrid_table_id).hide();
    },

    editurl: 'clientArray',
    page: 1,

    colModel: [{
        label: 'Site ID',
        name: 'siteId',
        width: 75,
        //key: true,  // The key field must be visible in order for the row to go into edit mode.
        sortable: false,
        editable: true,
        hidden: true,
        editrules: {
          edithidden: true
        }
      }, {
        label: 'Common MBU ID',
        name: 'commonMbuId',
        width: 75,
        //key: true,  // The key field must be visible in order for the row to go into edit mode.
        sortable: false,
        editable: true,
        hidden: true,
        editrules: {
          edithidden: true
        }
      }, {
        label: 'Parent Grid ID',
        name: 'parentGridId',
        width: 75,
        hidden: true
      },

      {
        label: 'Parent Row ID',
        name: 'parentRowId',
        width: 75,
        hidden: true
      }, {
        label: 'Geography',
        name: 'geocode',
        width: 90,
        sortable: true,
        key: true
      }, {
        label: 'City, State',
        name: 'cityName',
        width: 115,
        sortable: true
      }, {
        label: 'TA HHs',
        name: 'taHouseholds',
        width: 50,
        sortable: true,
        formatter: 'number',
        formatoptions: {
          thousandsSeparator: ",",
          decimalPlaces: 0
        },
        align: 'right'
      }, {
        label: 'Distr Qty',
        name: 'distribution',
        width: 50,
        sortable: true,
        formatter: 'number',
        formatoptions: {
          thousandsSeparator: ",",
          decimalPlaces: 0
        },
        align: 'right'
      }, {
        label: 'TA Distr',
        name: 'taDistribution',
        width: 50,
        sortable: false,
        hidden: true,
        formatter: 'number',
        formatoptions: {
          thousandsSeparator: ",",
          decimalPlaces: 0
        },
        align: 'right'
      },

      {
        label: 'CPM',
        name: 'cpm',
        width: 50,
        sortable: true,
        formatter: 'currency',
        formatoptions: {
          decimalSeparator: ".",
          thousandsSeparator: ",",
          decimalPlaces: 2,
          prefix: ""
        },
        align: 'right'
      },

      {
        label: 'Investment',
        name: 'investment',
        width: 90,
        sortable: true,
        formatter: 'currency',
        formatoptions: {
          decimalSeparator: ".",
          thousandsSeparator: ",",
          decimalPlaces: 2,
          prefix: "$ "
        },
        align: 'right'
      },

      {
        label: 'Coverage %',
        name: 'taCoverage',
        width: 85,
        sortable: true,
        formatter: 'currency',
        formatoptions: {
          decimalSeparator: ".",
          thousandsSeparator: ",",
          decimalPlaces: 2,
          suffix: " %"
        },
        align: 'right'
      },

      {
        label: 'Distance',
        name: 'distance',
        width: 75,
        sortable: true,
        formatter: 'number',
        formatoptions: {
          thousandsSeparator: ",",
          decimalPlaces: 2
        },
        align: 'right'
      },

      {
        label: 'Coverage Description',
        name: 'coverageDescDisplay',
        width: 90,
        sortable: true
      },

      {
        label: 'IH Date',
        name: 'ihDate',
        width: 60,
        sortable: true,
        //formatter: dateFormatter,
        align: 'center'
      },

      {
        label: 'IH Day',
        name: 'ihDay',
        width: 60,
        sortable: true,
        align: 'center'
      },

      {
        label: 'Pricing Market',
        name: 'pricingMarket',
        width: 115,
        sortable: true
      }, {
        label: ' ',
        name: 'variableValue',
        width: 90,
        sortable: true,
        hidden: false,
        align: 'right'
      },

      // Variable 1
      {
        label: ' ',
        name: 'var1Value',
        width: 90,
        sortable: true,
        hidden: false,
        align: 'right'
      },

      // Variable 2
      {
        label: ' ',
        name: 'var2Value',
        width: 90,
        sortable: true,
        hidden: false,
        align: 'right'
      },

      // Variable 3
      {
        label: ' ',
        name: 'var3Value',
        width: 90,
        sortable: true,
        hidden: false,
        align: 'right'
      }

    ],
    viewrecords: true,
    //height: '100%',
    shrinkToFit: false,
    width: 1400,
    rowNum: 20,
    pager: "#" + subgrid_pager_id
  });

}
```

And here's a link to the JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/msobczak/bebuyk67/3/

Hopefully the following pictures will help.

1. Initial grid rendering

[image: initial grid]

2. Grid display after scrolling the sub grid to the right.  Notice how the parent grid data columns are no longer in sync with the header columns.  In fact, the parent grid columns did not scroll at all.

[image: grid after scrolling sub grid to the right]

Comment: FYI: I tried my code using the latest jqgrid version of 5.0.2, and it has the same issue.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem using your JSFiddle demo, but I can't. After that I found that you use the latest source from my fork [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) instead of [Guriddio jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) 5.0.2. Only after replacing my free jqGrid to Guriddo jqGrid JS I get the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/bebuyk67/4/ which is buggy. Thus it shows that both Guriddo jqGrid JS versions 4.8.2 and 5.0.2 have probably the same bug. Probably it's more simple to stay by usage of free jqGrid?

Comment: In my jsFiddle, using free jQgrid, I didn't even get a scroll bar for the sub grid.  Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I have to remark that the demo https://jsfiddle.net/msobczak/bebuyk67/3/, which you included in the text of your question uses my fork of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) and *not* commercial [Guriddio jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) 4.8.2 or 5.0.2. The corresponding demo using the latest Guriddio jqGrid JS would be https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/bebuyk67/4/.

I made many fixes in free jqGrid. One from the changes, which I can see related to the problem, is the CSS rule

```css
.ui-jqgrid tr.ui-subgrid > td {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If I would add CSS rule to Guriddio jqGrid JS then I get https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/bebuyk67/5/, which hold subgrid always inside of the parent grid and the problem which you reported never exist.

**UPDATED:** If you want to see the horizontal scrollbar in the subgrid the you should reduce it's width by usage of

```js
$("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid("setGridWidth", $("#" + subgrid_id).width());
```

or, in more easy way, just by replacing explicit width (`width: 1400`) of subgrid to `autowidth: true` option. See the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/bebuyk67/7/

Comment: I see that there is now a vertical scroll bar on the right. However, I don't see a horizontal scroll bar for the sub grid, which is larger than the parent grid.  With the paid version of jqGrid, I get a horizontal scroll bar for the sub grid.  I apologize for not being clearer in my question, but that is the issue I'm trying to resolve: scrolling the sub grid causes the parent grid data to scroll, but not the parent grid header.

Comment: If I remove the additional CSS you added to the jsFiddle, I get back to the issue I had originally.

Comment: @MichaelSobczak: In my opinion the subgrid have to be **inside of the main grid**. If you need to see horizontal scroll bar in subgrid then follow **UPDATED** part and use `autowidth: true` instead of `width: 1400`: see https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/bebuyk67/7/

Comment: OK, that will work.  I would rather the data in the parent grid not scroll at all, than to scroll without the header row scrolling along with it.  The company I work for has paid for an enterprise license for the Guriddo product.  I don't think my company will be receptive to switching to the free version for this fix, unfortunately.  How would I get this behavior in the product we've paid for?

Comment: @MichaelSobczak: Sorry, but you paid not for me. I have no relation to Guriddio. On the opposite I develop alternative fork and provide it under MIT/GPLv2 for free, just ask to contribute the development by optional donating. Thus if you want to implement some fixes in Guriddo then you should contact http://guriddo.net/. On the other side I think that the changes, which I described in my answer should work with Guriddo (if no other bugs exists). See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/bebuyk67/8/ which use Guriddo.

Comment: OK, so the solution is to upgrade Guriddio and change the grid to use autoWidth.  Thanks for the input!