# jqGrid width subgrid pager exceeds main grid width

Tags: jqgrid, width, pager

I hope my title is comprehensive !
I am developing my own personal account with one main grid and one grid as subgrid.
The trouble is that main grid pager is displayed fine, but subgrid pager exceeds the width of grid, such as below :

[image]

I don't understand what is wrong.

Here is the subgrid code :

```
 subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
    var rowdata = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getRowData',row_id),
        catg=rowdata.cg_id,
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t",
        pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;
    $("#"+subgrid_id).closest("td").attr("colspan", 20)
    .css({
        borderRight:0,
        borderLeft:0,
        padding:0
    })
    .parent().find('td:eq(0)')
    .addClass('ui-widget-content')
    .addClass('ui-state-highlight')
    .css({
        borderLeft:0,
        borderTop:0
    });
    $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"'></div>");
    $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
        url:"subc.php?rowid="+row_id+"&catg="+catg,
        idPrefix:'s_'+row_id+'_',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ["ID","id_cp","Nom du poste"],
        colModel:[
            {
                name:"su_id",
                hidden:true
            },
            {
                name:"id_cg",
                hidden:true
            },
            {
                name:"su_name"
            }
        ],
        caption:"Liste des postes budgétaires",
        hidegrid: false,
        gridview: true,
        autowidth:true,
        shrinkToFit:false,
        viewrecords: true,
        recordtext: "Postes {0} - {1} of {2}",
        emptyrecords: "Aucun poste à afficher",
        rownumbers:true,
        rownumWidth:40,
        altRows:false,
        height:"auto",
        maxHeight: (23*15),
        rowNum: 20,
        pager: pager_id,
        loadComplete: function(){
            $("#gview_"+subgrid_table_id+" .ui-jqgrid-titlebar .ui-jqgrid-title").css({color:'#875', fontWeight:'bold', fontSize:'1.2rem', lineHeight:'1.3rem',marginLeft:'10px'});
        }
     });
     $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager_id,{search:false});
 }
```

I'm sure that's a newbie mistake, and I hope somebody could help me.
Many thanks in advance
Cheers
JiheL

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? I suppose that you use an old jqGrid or Guriddo. I answered some time before one close question and the problem was in the bug in non-free jqGrid versions. I develop free jqGrid and I fixed many old bugs. Try to use jqGrid directly from URLs described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) and verify whether you have still the same problem.

Comment: Changing of many styles and `colspan` shows that you try to solve some problems of jqGrid, which should not exist at all. By the way [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35418990/315935) is the question which I referenced before.